# Postgres sink connector placing messages in DLQ

Tags: postgresql, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

I am trying to explore postgres source and sink connectors on kafka. Created 2 tables in Postgres with same fields ( name varchar, created_at timestamp).

When the insert event happens on the table1, the source connector produce the message on the topic. The sink connector configured to consume the data from the topic and create the record into table2.

The event consuming is not happing on the sink connector and the messages are going to the DLQ queue.

```
Connector Class: PostgresSink 
Topics: development-source_test 
Max Tasks: 1 

input.data.format: JSON_SR 
connection.host: ****.ap-south-1.rds.amazonaws.com 
connection.port: 5432 
connection.user: devteam 
db.name: dev-db 
ssl.mode: prefer 
insert.mode: INSERT 
table.name.format: sink_test 
db.timezone: UTC 
auto.create: false 
auto.evolve: false 
tasks.max: 1
```

Comment: Please show both connector configs and their logs as part of a [mcve]

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the Connect logs as well